# Issue with Nested for loop in R

Tags: for-loop, matrix, subscript

I am trying to practice with R by reproducing an algorithm they gave to us in class for quantitative systems performances analysis. The output are Queue length (Q), Throughput (X) and service time (R) for a certain number of items (n) in the system and a certain number of machines (k).
I started with a simplified version when the number of machines=1 and the  code is working.

```
N1 <-c(1,2,3)
K1 <- 1
Q <- 0 
R <- 0
D <- 3 # service rate of the machine
for(z in 1:length(N1))
{if(z==1){R[z] <-D} else{R[z] <- 3*(1+Q[z-1])}
X<- z/R[z];
Q[z] <- X*R[z]}
```

Then, i tried for 4 machines. D stand for the service rate of each machine. So i created  a nested for loop. The code is the following.

```
N1 <-c(1,2)
K <- c(1,2,3,4)
D <- c(3,4,3,6) 
Q <- 0 
R <- 0
X <-0 
for(z in 1:length(N1)) 
  {for(k in 1:length(K))
  {if(z==1){R[k,z] <-D[k]} else{R[k,z] <- D[k]*(1+Q[k,z-1])}
  X[z]<- z/sum(R[z]); 
  if(z==1){Q[k,z] <- X[z]*R[k,z]} else {Q[k,z] <- X[z]*R[k,z]}
 }}
```

Although i fixed z==1, i get an error saying : "Error in R[k, z] <- D[k] : incorrect number of subscripts on matrix"
I am not sure how to proceed and i would appreciate any help. Just le me know in case more details are needed. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

You have to allocate the 2-dimensional matrix R

Use:

```
R <- matrix(nrow=length(K), ncol=length(N1))
```

Instead of:

```
R <- 0
```